# Cloudflare - Custom URL Purge not working on different accounts

Tags: cloudflare

What is the issue with Cloudflare custom URL purge caching not working on different accounts? Bascially I have the account, and this functionality does work, but my colleague who lives in USA, I live in Europe, for her this does not work.
Can the issues be with account settings? Basically she gets the error or sometimes the cache does not want to work

Answer (score 0):

I've faced issues in the past where features in Cloudflare was not working due to plugins or browser configuration. First you should confirm if the error is indeed coming from Cloudflare or from the browser.

Ask her to try to use a different browser and also a different device to confirm the issue is either tied to the account or to her location.

Try to inspect the page when performing the action to try and find out what's happening behind the scenes.